# why does `find` still try to access .gvfs AND even includes it in the output, despite `-prune`?

Tags: shell, find

<sub>beforehand: this evolved from a general question (I thought it was the case with every folder) to this specific corner case.

as it seemed that a few other people are as curious as myself, I decided to not delete this question but rework it.</sub>

---

Let's say I want to list all items contained direct in my home folder, except the dot files & folders. IMHO, the following find command should do this *(I explicitly wrote "dot items", because if you use a `.hidden` file the "hidden items" may differ)*:

```
find $HOME/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -path "$HOME/.*" -prune -o -print
```

`-mindepth 1` to ensure that $HOME itself is not included, `-maxdepth 1` to limit to one folder level, `-path "$HOME/.*" -prune` to exclude everything in the home folder starting with a dot and `-o -print` to ensure that not the excluded elements are in the output according to the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Directories.html).

So far, so good. It kind of works (even if there are dot-folders for which you don't have the permissions), **but** it starts to choke on `$HOME/.gvfs` although it shouldn't be accessed at all due to `-path ... -prune`:

```
/home/user/file a
/home/user/folder b
...
find: '/home/user/.gvfs': Permission denied
/home/user/.gvfs
...
/home/user/file z
```

I know I can use `-perm` at `find` and `2> /dev/null` to work around it, but what really appalled me is, that **`/home/user/.gvfs` is included in the list** (although all other dot items are excluded)!!!
and I'm pretty sure some not so careful people are tempted to get rid of the error with `2> /dev/null` and move on. ...**if** they recognize the error at all, because at longer lists with a few 100 lines you have to explicitly check for errors with something like adding `1> /dev/null` prior to working with that command.

---

#### really ignoring a directory/tree?

Why is `find` trying to access `/home/user/.gvfs` at all, despite `-maxdepth 1` or at least `-prune` should prevent this? e.g. from the man page:

> ‘-prune’ action (which only **prevents further descent** [...])

even in an older man page (installed on my system) for `-path` it is stated:

> To **ignore a whole directory tree**,  use  -prune  rather than  checking every file in the tree.

#### dangerous listing of an "ignored" directory itself!

If all `/home/user/.*` would be really ignored, perhaps the second part of my question won't be necessary, as it seems to me this is because of an internal error:
why is `/home/user/.gvfs` still in the list and how to prevent it? Is there a way without fiddling around with `-user`/`-perm` and `2> /dev/null` for every `find` command (at least with a `-prune` action)?

#### future usage -> efficiency?

What is really ignored with `-prune` (or at least with `-path ... -prune`)?

If with `-prune` still (nearly) all files are checked, I would ditch using this complicated option and rather use `!` or `-not`, especially as `-prune` is apparently much more error-prone.

Comment: "interesting"... i fired up a virgin machine and tried to reproduce it, but no luck. only when using `-maxdepth 2` **and** without `-prune` i get the permission error, which is obvious. **||** it seems that the older machine where i tested it, is somehow f*ed up or at least its gvfs. :-(

Comment: now i'm curious why the heck i get this permission error although nevertheless `$HOME/.gvfs` would match the `-prune` test (even if f*ed up)! but i'm afraid i'll never know...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas whether this works as in sfind, depends on two things: 1) the OS and the find implementation both need to support the fle type in struct dirent. 2) The callback function from the treewalker in the find implementation needs to abort the traversal early with -maxdepth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be [a bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60207#comment0) in the GNU implementation of `find`. Here, the trigger seems to be the fact that the `lstat()` / `fstatat()` system call (to retrieve a file's metadata) fails with `EACCESS` (*permission denied*) on that `.gvfs` file.

That typically happens on Linux for files that are mount points of FUSE-based file systems for which the `-o allow-other` option has not being used. That can also happen with `find -L` / `find -follow` when there are symlinks that point to inaccessible areas.

I find here that `-prune` for those files returns *false* which is clearly a bug as `-prune` is documented (and required by POSIX) to always return *true*.

As a work around until that bug is fixed, you can replace `-prune` with `'(' -prune -o -true ')'` (note that `-true` is a GNU extension; a portable equivalent could be `! -name ''` which is guaranteed to be true, though you could also do `'(' -prune -o ! -prune ')'`)

Now, there are a few issues with your code itself. In:

```
find $HOME/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -path "$HOME/.*" -prune -o -print
```

- In most Bourne-like shells, that `$HOME/` should be quoted as otherwise the `$HOME` expansion is subject to split+glob. You could also write it `~/`.
- `-prune` is to tell `find` not to descend into a directory. Here it's superfluous as `maxdepth 1` will stop `find` from descending into any directory (other than the top-level (depth 0) one `$HOME/`).
- `-path` takes a pattern. That means that the contents of `$HOME` will be taken as a pattern. If your `$HOME` is for instance `/home/[112] me`, `-path '/home/[112] me/.*'` would match on `/home/2 me/.foo`, but not on `/home/[112] me/.foo`. Also matching on the full path here is not necessary, you can match on the file name instead with `-name '.*'`.
- `*` with GNU `find` only matches on *characters*, so `.*` matches on filenames that start with `.` **and** are also made of sequences of bytes that form valid characters. So you can only use that to match hidden files in locales where every sequence of byte form valid characters (such as the `C` locale).

So here, if the point is to list the non-hidden files in your HOME directory with their full paths, you'd do:

```
LC_ALL=C find ~/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*'
```

Which would also avoid that GNU `find` bug.

Or the standard equivalent (though adds a `/./` in the paths):

```
LC_ALL=C find ~/. ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*'
```

(here, the GNU `find` bug would be hit for files that do *not* start with `.` and are not `lstat()`able, but you'll see at that bug description above that whether non-`lstat()`able files are reported or not varies greatly with the implementation).

Here, I'd just use `zsh`'s:

```
print -rC1 ~/*(ND)
```

Or if you don't want them sorted like with `find`:

```
print -rC1 ~/*(NDoN)
```

Comment: yes, in this case using `-prune` is superfluous, but this is just a pretty tuned down version of an other find command (trying to make it as short & easy as possible but still to have some kind of sense behind it).

Comment: usually i quote "everything". ;-) ...no idea how this one slipped trough. - correct quoting is one of the most basic & important but IMHO also difficult topics, and sadly very few seem to care about it.

Comment: last but not least: i try to avoid `LC_ALL=C` in conjunction `find` because it butchers language specific characters resp. replaces them with `??`.

Comment: Only when the output goes to a terminal and only with GNU `find`. You can always pipe the output to `cat` to work around it.

Comment: awesome ideas for the workarounds!!! both are so simple and easy, but therefore genius! thank you very much @StéphaneChazelas!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy If your find implementation causes problems with LC_ALL=C, this is a bug in your find. You may like to use sfind instead, see the schilytools source tarball. BTW: Stephane recently discovered a similar problem in the Bourne Shell and the next source release (most likely next week) wil fix this problem in the Bourne Shell that is caused by converting to and from wide characters. the important point is here that applications like find need to be locale agnostic, since the character encoding on UNIX is user specific and not platform specific.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas about your workarounds: are you sure about the "double-prune"? because `-prune` returns per definition "always" true: so i would guess it should be rather `'(' -prune -o -prune ')'` (simply `-prune` instead of `-true` as in your first workaround). ...or does the second `-prune` also return false because of the bug in conjunction with the first one?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy, the point of that bug is that there are files in corner cases for which `-prune` returns false. And that's regardless of how many time you call it, there's no reason why `-prune` would start to work properly when called several times. You can test yourself by replacing the command with `find . -name 'a*' \( -prune -o -prune \) -o -print` in the test case at the bug report linked in this answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for clarification. ...i wasn't sure if all `-prune` will return false because of this bug.